# Mysql select with Where and default if where condition not present

Tags: mysql, selection, where-clause

I have tables Product and productDetails. In productDetails I have rows with description of product in many languages (discriminated by lang column). Not every product will have description in every language. How to make a selection that will select the description in the specified language (by `Where productDescription.lang = 'en'`) and that will select a description in a default language if the specified language is not present (descriptions with default language are always present).

I made this:

```
select *
  from product
  left join productDetails on product.id = productDetails.product_id
 where productDetails.language = 'en';
```

and I get all details in en language. How to modify this to make details in default language selected if en is not present?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the default language code?  It is presumably not `'en'` in this case.

Comment: Some language I choose to be default on webpage. If there is no translation for some data, they should be display in default language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that. I don't know your exact schema:

```
select 
   p.id, 
   if(IS NULL d2.description, d1.description, d2.description ) `description`
 from product p
 join productDetails d1
   on product.id = productDetails.product_id
      and
   productDetails.language = 'default_lang'
 left join productDetails d2
   on product.id = productDetails.product_id 
      and
   productDetails.language = 'en'
```

Comment: I have no nulls in tables. There could be rows with descriptions with 'pl', 'en', it', etc. but not every language is oblitagory. I want to select rows from joined tables in specified language but if there is no description with this language I want to select row in default language (which is always present).

Comment: When you run `left join` to description table you will see null in d2.description column. Then you can select by `if` function default or translated value.

Comment: `select p.id, coalesce(d2.description, d1.description) as description,
from product p join productDetails d1
on p.id = d1.product_id and d1.language = 'default'
left join productDetails d2
on p.id = d2.product_id and d2.language = 'en'`
works well. Thanks.